# private unicode character in HTML

Tags: html, unicode

I am rendering following HTML in browser:

```
<p>
<span lang="en-EN"style="font-family: Symbol;"> &#61623; </span>
</p>
```

This renders to a "bullet". However if I try to get the innerHTML for this element I get an empty square for `&#61623`;
How do I ensure I get `&#61623`; ?

The above example is contrived. I am actually using CKEditor to render and edit some text from the server. The above HTML renders to a "bullet" in CKEditor when received from server. But on save the HTML sent to server does not contain `&#61623`;

Can someone throw light on what's going on here. [ I know that this is a private unicode character. When this is rendered properly in web browser why is this not sent to server properly]

Comment: You get a character with the code 61623. The actual shape of the character depends on the font. What else would you want to get?

Comment: When we are sending this HTML to server we are getting a "?" mark for &#61623. Does it mean the editor i.e. CKEditor has a different understanding for &#61623 ?How do we send &#61623 to the server for storing so that this is returned to client on next call ?

Comment: Depends on your text editor. I have just inserted <U+F0B7> using Gvim in an HTML file served by Apache 2.4 and it was correctly served as <U+F0B7>. Note that this being a private use character its shape must be agreed beforehand between the server and the client by making sure that the client uses the correct font; the statement "this renders as a bullet" is true _only for a client which uses the specific font agreed beforehand_; in a client which is not privy to the agreement it may render as , or as a wheel with eleven spokes, or as a shark or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The 61623- issue occurs for get data while using:

```
(wtable.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow>().ElementAt(j)).Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell>().ElementAt(k).InnerText
```